# Django Rest Framework With JWT user authentication (getting anonymous user )

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-authentication

I am using JWT with Django to Authenticate requests from Ajax jquery . My Jquery is

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/customerapi/get-customer-detail/",
        type: 'GET',
        // headers: {"Token": localStorage.getItem('token')},
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        /* Authorization header */
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Token " + localStorage.getItem('token'));
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Mobile", "false");
         },

        success: function (res) {

        }
    });
```

And when I get this request on server I authenticate like this

```
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated

class GetCustomerData(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (JSONWebTokenAuthentication,  )
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated ,)
    def get(self, request):
        try:
        Customer.objects.get(id=request.user)
```

here my Request.user is always anonymous. Why this this is happening?

and my middleware classes are

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `JWT` instead of `Token` inside header value:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "JWT " + localStorage.getItem('token'));
```

Comment: thanks sir <3 . working on localhost now but returning anon user on live . when I checked  header on live  by doing  request.headers['Authorization']   it gives    'Request' object has no attribute 'headers'

Comment: Even request.META['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'],  is not carrying my header. Do you have any clue what can be issue ?